# Programmatically Fetching Google+ status updates

Tags: java, android, google-plus

Is there a way to programmatically fetch Google+ updates for a user's profile? I can't seem to find much in the documentation at https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/people  and http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/plus/model/people/Person.html  about fetching statuses. I would like to fetch the data by making an HTTP request or if there is some sort of SDK for Android that will help me, that would work to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The API you are looking for is [plus.activities.list](https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/activities/list). This will list the Google+ equivalent of Facebook status updates. The referenced page has example code to get you started.

When accessing the API, you should [use the Google API client as documented here](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/getting-started).

Answer (score 1):

The following code will be useful to retrieve the Http responses.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken;

public class GooglePlusStatusHelper {

    public GooglePlusStatusHelper() {
    }


    public static void main(String... args) {

        GooglePlusStatusHelper googlePlusStatusHelper = new GooglePlusStatusHelper();
        try {
            googlePlusStatusHelper.tagsUsed();
        }  catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    private void tagsUsed() throws IOException {
        URL url = createQuery("users");
        Type dataType = new TypeToken<Wrapper<Status>>(){}.getType();
        Status status = executeQuery(url, dataType);

        System.out.println(status);
    }

    private URL createQuery(String inputParam) throws MalformedURLException {
        String baseUrl = "http://api.example.com/" + inputParam ;
        System.out.println(baseUrl);
        URL url = new URL(baseUrl);
        return url;
    }

    private Status executeQuery(URL url, Type clz) throws IOException {

        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.connect();
        System.out.println("Response Code:" + conn.getResponseCode());
        System.out.println("Response Message:" + conn.getResponseMessage());
        System.out.println("TYPE:" + conn.getContentType());

        InputStream content = conn.getInputStream();
        String encoding = conn.getContentEncoding();
        if (encoding != null && encoding.equals("gzip")) {
            content = new GZIPInputStream(content);
        }
        String result = new Scanner(content, "UTF-8").useDelimiter("\\A").next();
        content.close();

        Gson gson = new Gson();
        return gson.fromJson(result, clz);
    }

}
```

Status class :

```
 public class Status {

    private int count;
    private String status;
    ......

    public String toString() {
        String result = "\ncount: " + count +
                "\status:" + status;

        result = result + "\n------------";
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Is there any official documentation anywhere online for doing this?